# Sending a message to an application running on a secondary logged in user account

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying to send a message to an application running under a different user account (a user that is also logged in with a different account on the computer, using quick user switch on XP and later, and executed the application).

The background is that my application can update itself, but in order to do that all running instances must be closed first.
The instances need to be shut down (instead of just killing the process), so the updater does that by sending a custom message to them (with `SendMessage`). In order to send a message I need a handle to the main window of the process.

This works fine using `EnumWindows` - as long as the instances are running under the same user account, because `EnumWindows` does not list windows belonging to a different user.

So I tried a different approach. I used `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to first list all running processes on the system, and then iterating through the threads calling `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` again. With those thread ids I could then list their windows using `EnumThreadWindows`.

Once again this works fine, but.. once again only for the current logged in user. The problem here is that even though `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` lists process ids belonging to a different user it does not list thread ids belonging to them. The code for this is a little lengthy, but if it's required I can edit it in - please leave a comment for that.

So, how could I get the main window handle of my application running on a different logged in user account?

Comment: You may need to use something like named pipes to get around these security restrictions. What you are trying to do is akin to session 0 services communicating with the interactive desktop and so solutions that work there will work for you.

Comment: It's also seems to me to be a bit mean to shut down the user's processes without giving them a chance to object. Most updaters just wait until the next time the app starts to perform update.

Comment: +1 to David's. Even Windows warns you about other logged on users if you try to shutdown while there's an other active session. Anything that "talks" to processes across session boundary is a bit awkward and scary. Just image an application popping something like `The user "Administrator" has this document opened, would you like me to shut down that process so you can work on the document?`

Comment: I know it's rather rude behaviour. It's a background application though (but not a service), and usually doesn't interact with the user (just has an icon in the system tray). I wouldn't do this with real interactive applications either, but I think it's ok for a background one, which automatically restarts after an update. Waiting for the next start would be an alternative solution, but requires some major changes in design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use something that's known to work across sessions; This kind of stuff is often used for desktop-service communications, so look for that if you want to google. Here's my suggestion:

1. Create an event that will only be used to trigger the "need to shut down" state. Use the [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function make sure you start your name with `Global\` so it's valid across sessions.
2. On application startup create a thread that opens the named event (uses the same `CreateEvent` function, pay close attention to the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` non-error). That thread should simply wait for the event. When the event is triggered, send the required message to your main window. That thread can easily and safely do that because it's running *inside* your process. The thread will mostly be idle, waiting for the event to be triggered, so don't worry about CPU penalty.
3. Your application updateer should simply trigger the named event.

This is just one idea, I'm sure there are others.

Comment: +1 deleting my answer. completely forgot about Events which is the best solution in this case.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem perfectly. It was a little tricky at first, because I had to set a security descriptor allowing access to everyone upon creating the event. Otherwise I got an access denied error when I tried opening the event with a different account. But now it works, so thanks :-)

Comment: Please note that creating objects in the Global namespace requires the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege unless you are doing this in the console session. Only administrators have this privilege. This behaviour is documented here (last paragraph): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Remko: From that article: `The privilege check is limited to the creation of file-mapping objects`. I tested it with a restricted user account (on Win 7 and XP), and restricted users were able to create the event in the global namespace aswell.

Comment: @Chris: I verified as well and indeed a user can create an event in the Global namespace, even from a non console session.

Answer (score 7):

Pipes are overkill.  A global manual-reset event (e.g. "Global\MyApplicationShutdownEvent") which causes application instances to kill themselves should be enough.

Comment: Though I agree with David Heffernan.  This is rather rude.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being scoffed at, have you looked at [zeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), this is a perfect use for it and it very reliable and stable.

There is a [Delphi wrapper](http://www.danieleteti.it/zeromq-for-delphi/)